# A contradictory result from a lemma about the dimensions of ambient spaces of a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds

To remove ambiguity, I already gave related definitions at the end of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4311842/the-dimension-of-the-cartesian-product-of-two-manifolds) question.

- A subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is  called a smooth $n$-dimensional **manifold** if $\forall x \in X$, $\exists$ a diffeomorphism $\varphi: U \to V$ such that $V$ is open in $X$, $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $x \in V$. Then $\varphi$ is called a **local parameterization** of $V$. The inverse $\varphi^{-1}$ is called a **local coordinate system**, or **chart**, on $V$.
- *Lemma:* Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb R^m$, $B$ open in $\mathbb R^n$, and $f:A \to B$ a diffeomorphism. Then $m = n$. [A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4311551/let-a-subseteq-mathbb-rm-b-subseteq-mathbb-rn-and-fa-to-b-be-a-d)]

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold and $x \in X$. Let $\varphi: U \to V$ be a local parameterization around $x \in V$.  Here $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb R^N$. It follows that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism. By our Lemma, $n=N$.

Clearly, the statement $n=N$ is not correct, but I could not spot the error. Could you elaborate on where is my logical mistake?

Comment: The point is that unless $n=N$ an open nbhd $x \in V \subseteq X$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and so you are not in a position to invoke the stated Lemma.

Comment: @FriederJäckel Ahh It's that $V$ is open in $X$ and that $V$ is not necessarily open in $\mathbb R^N$. So we can not invoke our lemma.

Comment: Exactly. As an example take the following: Let $X=S^2$, $U=B_1(0) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $V\subseteq S^2$ the upper half sphere and $\varphi: U \to V$ given by $\varphi (x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$. This is clearly a parametrization and $V$ is open in $S^2$, but not open in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: You should define what you mean by a local parameterization of a manifold. I guess it is not that what one usually denotes as a *chart* around $x \in X$.

Comment: Hi @PaulFrost question updated.

Comment: And "diffeomorphism" in the definition of *local parameterization* has to be understood in the sense of your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4312369 ? By the way, writing " Here $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ " is not consistent with the definition. You need $V \subseteq X$.

Comment: @PaulFrost yess, diffeomorphism is understood in the sense given in that thread. That's why I posted that thread :) Writing $V \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ is not incorrect but it made me miss the point that $V$ is open in $X$, not in $\mathbb R^N$.  This is where the collapse begins.

Comment: @PaulFrost my recent questions seem to be pedantic and repetitive of basic concepts. I'm sorry if they cause inconvenience to other people. The lecture [note](https://minterscompactness.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/Differential_Geometry_Part_II_Notes.pdf) will be progressively harder with the introduction of new concepts and interaction of old ones. This approach to study is to make things clear from the beginning, i.e., just one time and for all.

Comment: @Akira Don't worry, in my opinion your questions do not cause inconvenience, but show that you are thinking about something. There are other questions in this forum which seem to have the character "here is my homework, solve the problem for me", but this does not apply here. But I suggest that you answer your own question to clear it from the unanswered queue.

Comment: One nitpick: You say "writing $V \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ is not incorrect". Of course this inclusion holds true when $V \subseteq \mathbb X$, but imo it is a very infelicitous wording to say that  a $V \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ is open in $X$ because that only makes sense for $V \subseteq \mathbb X$. And perhaps you find https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3511868 useful.

Comment: @PaulFrost I actually did it before. When I post an answer like "@somebody's comment solves my question. I post it here as an answer to remove my question from the unanswered list", my answer has been deleted or voted to be deleted by some users. Those people feel that such my "answer" does not meet the standard of an answer. Then I feel that it's safer to let it be, i.e., not post such answers.